# How do I use MAMP standard on a Mac?

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I have tried this 3 or 4 times, but it seems like the only version is MAMP pro, every time I install the .pkg file, it installs MAMP pro, the MAMP standard and pro version seems (according to the  docs) to be bundled together with the pro version. The docs say the standard version will work after the demo pro expires but all it does it lock down the entire app.

"This download package for Mac OS X contains the free MAMP and a free 14-day trial of MAMP PRO. MAMP can be used stand-alone without MAMP PRO."

^ Does this "stand-alone" even exist?

I selected customize, and I un-checked the Pro version but it does not do this. Every time I launch the app I have a demo expired error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAMP.app (the thing you need) is buried inside of the MAMP/ folder (unlike the pro version) so if you are good at where's waldo, then you won't have any trouble since its in a folder with dozens of other things that all render the same looking on Mac. PC users probably don't have this issue.